# How do I apply my magnifier on multple images on a single page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

```js
// magnify hover
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {
  var img, glass, w, h, bw;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
  /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
    if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
    if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
    /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}
/* Initiate Magnify Function
with the id of the image, and the strength of the magnifier glass:*/
magnify("mag", 5);
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-magnifier-container {
  position:relative;
}

.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
  width: 120px;
  height: 130px;
  opacity:0;
  pointer-events:none;
}
a:hover .img-magnifier-glass{
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events:initial;
}
```

```html
<table class="img-magnifier-container" width="115" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: inline-block"><tr><td width="115" style="text-align: center"><center><a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478970/" title="Ant-Man (2015)" target="_blank"><img class="cover" width="115" height="133" border="0" id="mag" class="pstrart" id="pstr" src="https://images2.static-bluray.com/movies/covers/238380_front.jpg" style=""></a></center><center><input type="checkbox" name="movieboxes" value="Ant-Man" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin: 0px;">
<img title="United Kingdom" border="2" class="flag" id="flgborder" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/530906893443399683/665554365897244693/union-jack-26119_960_720.png" style="width: 25px; height: 17px;">
</center></td></tr></table>&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<table class="img-magnifier-container" width="115" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: inline-block"><tr><td width="115" style="text-align: center"><center><a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6644200/" title="A Quiet Place (2018)" target="_blank"><img class="cover" width="115" height="133" border="0" id="mag" class="pstrart" id="pstr" src="https://images2.static-bluray.com/movies/covers/202637_front.jpg" style=""></a></center><center><input type="checkbox" name="movieboxes" value="A Quiet Place" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin: 0px;">
<img title="United Kingdom" border="2" class="flag" id="flgborder" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/530906893443399683/665554365897244693/union-jack-26119_960_720.png" style="width: 25px; height: 17px;">
</center></td></tr></table>&nbsp;
&nbsp;
```

Hello,

I recently made a magnifier on hover using the help from people on this website. However, I don't konw how to make it so I can have the magnifier on all the images instead of just the first one. I provided two images in the snippet on this post so you can see what I mean.

Thank you for any information!

Comment: The main reason why your code doesn't work is because you are using duplicate IDs in your markup: not only the image element, but also other elements in the document, too.

Also, since you only invoke your `mag()` method once, it initializes with the first element that matches the ID. You will need to implement some iterative logic in there to apply to every single image element that matches a certain criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further elabourate on my comment: the main issue is that:

1. You have duplicate IDs and duplicate attributes in multiple elements on your page. You should always use unique IDs within a document, and instead of having multiple `class` attributes per element, you should combine them into one.
2. You are initializing the magnify logic on a single element. You are lacking iterative logic to step through all the images that you want to magnify.

---

My suggestion is that:

1. Fix the DOM mistakes as stated above. Also, give your image elements that you want to magnify a common class, so we can select all of them. Example is `class="magnify-image"`, but you can use any arbitrary class names that you want.
2. You update the `magnify()` method to accept an image element instead of an ID: that will mean that our iterative logic can pass in the image element you want to magnify directly. Rewriting it to be `function magnify(img, zoom) { ... }` and then remove the `var img = ...` assignment is sufficient.
3. You give each image you want to magnify a class, and then select for all these images to create a HTMLCollection. Iterate through this collection and simply pass the image element in each iteration as the first argument.

Example of iterative logic:

```
// Iterate through all images you want to magnify
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.magnify-image');
Array.from(images).forEach((image) => {
    // We pass the actual image element into the function
    magnify(image, 5);
});
```

If you absolutely have to support ES5, then we can do this:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('magnify-image');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(images, function(image) {
    // We pass the actual image element into the function
    magnify(image, 5);
});
```

See proof-of-concept:

```js
// magnify hover
function magnify(img, zoom) {
  var glass, w, h, bw;
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
  /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);

  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {
      x = img.width - (w / zoom);
    }
    if (x < w / zoom) {
      x = w / zoom;
    }
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {
      y = img.height - (h / zoom);
    }
    if (y < h / zoom) {
      y = h / zoom;
    }
    /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0,
      y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };
  }
}

// Iterate through all images you want to magnify
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.magnify-image');
Array.from(images).forEach((image) => {
  
  magnify(image, 5);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-magnifier-container {
  position: relative;
}

.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
  width: 120px;
  height: 130px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

a:hover .img-magnifier-glass {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: initial;
}
```

```html
<table class="img-magnifier-container" width="115" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: inline-block">
  <tr>
    <td width="115" style="text-align: center">
      <center>
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0478970/" title="Ant-Man (2015)" target="_blank"><img width="115" height="133" border="0" class="cover pstrart magnify-image" src="https://images2.static-bluray.com/movies/covers/238380_front.jpg" style=""></a>
      </center>
      <center><input type="checkbox" name="movieboxes" value="Ant-Man" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin: 0px;">
        <img title="United Kingdom" border="2" class="flag" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/530906893443399683/665554365897244693/union-jack-26119_960_720.png" style="width: 25px; height: 17px;">
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>&nbsp; &nbsp;
<table class="img-magnifier-container" width="115" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: inline-block">
  <tr>
    <td width="115" style="text-align: center">
      <center>
        <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6644200/" title="A Quiet Place (2018)" target="_blank"><img width="115" height="133" border="0" class="cover pstrart magnify-image" src="https://images2.static-bluray.com/movies/covers/202637_front.jpg" style=""></a>
      </center>
      <center><input type="checkbox" name="movieboxes" value="A Quiet Place" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; margin: 0px;">
        <img title="United Kingdom" border="2" class="flag" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/530906893443399683/665554365897244693/union-jack-26119_960_720.png" style="width: 25px; height: 17px;">
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>&nbsp; &nbsp;
```